# Smart vs Intelligent vs Adaptive vs Advance (etc) Embedded Devices

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, hardware, firmware, smart

I hope my question is not off-topic here. I am asking it here because it is directly related to the hardware devices which are primarily based on MCU's. These Embedded System devices are used every where everyday.

Let us say the device is a 'Time Attendance Device".
https://www.alibaba.com/showroom/face-recognition-time-attendance-system.html

Unlike what the Device manual says about its capabilities I want to know when to say that a device is:

1. Intelligent
2. Smart
3. Adaptive
4. Advance
5. Fault-tolerant
6. Self-healing/repairing
7. Innovative
   etc.

These days I see these words are used without knowledge of their exact technical meanings in the devices marketing manuals.

I wonder when to attribute the above properties with a certain device? Are these attributes related to the Firmware design or Hardware design of an Embedded system device or both?

What could be the minimum requirement to say that a specific device has one of the above attributes in it?

Edit:
I want to know when it will be "technically" correct to attribute any of the above properties to an Embedded system device.

Comment: Interesting question. Being a recent university graduate, I grew up with feeling that the words you mentioned in the question do not actually have common and precisely defined technical meanings, but I could just be too new.

Comment: This is both off topic here, and primarily a question of opinion.  It is not a design question.

Comment: These are empty words.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I wanted to know when it will be "technically" correct to attribute any of the above properties to an Embedded system device. I am not looking for 'opinions' in this question. I think this is largely linked with the design aspect of the device more than any other of its aspect as its business or operations etc.

Comment: Those are NOT technical terms. Those are marketing terms. Big difference.

Comment: It's marketing barf than means nothing without a specific context. Compare for example "smart phone" with "smart high side driver"... those are wildly different things so how would you define "smart"?

Comment: What you are not understanding is that no technical answer is possible, the only meaning of these or qualification under them is an opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most are marketing BS, intelligent, smart, innovative, advanced, mean absolutely nothing.

Some of the more precise things might mean at least a bit of what they intend to convey, but how well they execute that is another matter.

Adaptive - it should self adjust to something or other. ADSL modems test the quality of the line before deciding on a speed, does that count?

Fault tolerant - what faults, what degree of service after faults? Doesn't catch fire, automatically reconnects after disconnection? Totally meaningless without details.

Self-healing - after what faults? Does it have RAID drives and can survive a drive failure, or is it two complete computers, or does it test its RAM from time to time and avoid bad cells? Totally different threat models and behaviour.

As the details would be complicated, with luck defined in the data sheet, any headline description is not going to tell you anything meaningful. Their proper use is limited to pointing you towards the data sheet. Their main use is to get you to notice the product, and hopefully buy it without investigating the details.